# как удалить элемент с массива

Tags: javascript

Если элемент имеет активный класс то нужно добавить его `id` в массив, если при клике на активный элемент, то удалить активный класс и удалить его `id` из массива. Как можно удалить уже добавленный элемент из массива?

```
.elem {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 50px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            background-color: orange;
        }
        .elem.active {
            background-color: green;
        }

<div class="elem" id="elem-1">1</div>
    <div class="elem" id="elem-2">2</div>
    <div class="elem" id="elem-3">3</div>
    <div class="elem" id="elem-4">4</div>

function ready() {
    let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".elem"),
        arr = [];

    for (let i = 0; elems.length > i; i++) {
        elems[i].onclick = function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            let elemId = this.getAttribute("id");
            if (this.classList.contains("active") === true) {
                if (arr.indexOf(elemId) === -1) {
                    arr.push(elemId);
                }
            } else {

            }
            console.log(arr);
        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью метода [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) найти индекс элемента в массиве, а потом с помощью метода [.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) удалить его из массива.

```js
function ready() {
  let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".elem"),
    arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; elems.length > i; i++) {
    elems[i].onclick = function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      let elemId = this.getAttribute("id");
      if (this.classList.contains("active") === true) {
        if (arr.indexOf(elemId) === -1) {
          arr.push(elemId);
        }
      } else {
        let index = arr.indexOf(elemId);
        if (index >= 0) {
          arr.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
      console.log(arr);
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

```css
.elem {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.elem.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem" id="elem-1">1</div>
<div class="elem" id="elem-2">2</div>
<div class="elem" id="elem-3">3</div>
<div class="elem" id="elem-4">4</div>
```